# Cron job to run every 1st day of the month

Tags: cron

I need to create a cron job that will run on the every 1st day of the month every minute of this day. I will create it from cpanel.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: yes, but i want to run the page every minute of this day (1st day of the month).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The crontab entry should look like this :

```
* * 1 * * cmd_to_run
```

The columns mean

every minute

every hour

1st day of month

every month

any day of week, and then the command.

I'm not sure about cpanel admin

Comment: ok that entry will run the page once every 1st day of month. but i want to run it every minute of this day.

Comment: It appears you haven't quite understood the syntax completely. Try and think about how cron works. It wakes up once a minute, gets the time and then compares this time against the crontab entries to see if it must start a process. The only constraint in my entry is "the day must be one", so it will run every minute during any hour but only when the day of month is 1.

Comment: yes, i'm sorry your entry is works fine.

Comment: I suppose that instead of "any minute" and "any hour", etc., it should be "every minute", etc. Although I think the day of week section really is more like "any". Putting * there, unlike the other places, does not cause it to run for all days. Right?

Comment: And for the casual skimmer who didn't quite get this, this entry will run for every minute that day. If you want it to run on a particular minute, then you could replace the first two asterisks with something like 0 5, which would mean 5:00 AM on the system clock.

Comment: @Volomike Yep, that's what the op wanted. Every minute the first day of the month.