# How to run a PHP script automatically in every month

Tags: php, cron

I have the php project for user can register and buy the hours to listen music or video, the not used of 50% hours have to rollover to next month, I wanted to automate this process when user complete one month I have to check their usage and process the rollover using php. I have following user details on DB, Signed-up date with time and usage and hours they purchased and used hours. I want to do it once in a month for each customer.

Is it possible using cron jobs? I don't have any idea to do this.

Comment: Assuming there are users registering every day at any given hour, checking this only once a month wont do. It wont have passed 1 month for everyone at the same time. You have to check frequently for expired users.

Comment: And cron job is this: https://cron-job.org/en/

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874784/cron-job-to-run-every-1st-day-of-the-month

Comment: @Havenard Sorry, I meant each users once in a month

Comment: You are not supposed to schedule a script run for every user. Just check hourly for users that expired and do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right approach but I've been running such kind of scripts when a user logs into his account.

For example.

You can do something like on successful login request by the user

```
if(date of buying hours has crossed the specified limit) /here you can check for expiry date/
{ // run your script here
     }
else{}
```

just a suggestion!

You don't need to update all of the records all at once. Just update it for the user who logs in. 
At the end, it will be updated for every user I think.

Comment: No that's bad idea, Some users may not logged into their account, It should be update when user automatically renews to next month. Anyway thanks for your time

Comment: If user does not login, it should not matter if hours are 30 or 15

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Use Cron job.

Syntax and usage of how to use it is almost straight forward. Here's a [cheat sheet](http://bencane.com/2012/09/03/cheat-sheet-crontab-by-example/).

**Note:** If you're on a shared host, some hosts don't allow you to use cron job.

**Edit:** What @Havenard suggested is correct. The below cron job will visit the url once at minute 00 of every hour:

```
0 * * * * wget http://www.mywebsite.com/some/link
```

Comment: I have dedicated server, But corn jobs while affect server performance?

Comment: @GoldPearl Normally it's fine to run cron jobs, even multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

yes this possible with Cron Job **1st** Create your php file with your condition use update query then add this cron job file in your server Cron Job Section and select date when you want to run this file. in cron job just file your cronjobfile.php name , Date and time when this file run.